# Seeding date in EF 2.1

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I am using new way of seeding data in Entity Framework 2.1:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Blog>().HasData(new Blog {BlogId = 1, CreateDate = DateTime.Now});
```

However, applying this to the database throws an exception `Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string`. I can see that in the generated SQL the value comes as `'2018-06-01T13:22:13.248-07:00'` which is wrong. And since the field is obviously `DateTime`, I can't format it into the string the way I would want to.

Is it a bug in EF? Or I am missing something obvious? In the *traditional* EF code it works fine:

```
Blog.CreateDate = DateTime.Now;
...
context.SaveChanges();
```

Or maybe there is some workaround on the SQL side that would allow it to take date in this format?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue 1 here is the conversion failure. This can be solved by converting the column to DateTime2.
Reference: [Seeding DateTime in EF 2.1 throws exception #12211](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/12211)

Issue 2 (DateTime.Now becomes a fixed date/time) is something I looking into as well.

Answer (score 0):

Use {[Column(TypeName = "datetime")] annotation

```
public class Blog
{[Column(TypeName = "datetime")]
public DateTime CreateDate { get; set; }
```